# masking the password('abcs') clause to password('****') using regex in cpp

Tags: c++, regex

I have a functions that turns the string :

```
 select * from run_on_hive(server('hdp230m2.labs.teradata.com'),username('vijay'),password('vijay'),dbname('default'),query('analyze table default.test01 compute statistics'));
```

to:

```
 select * from run_on_hive(server('hdp230m2.labs.teradata.com'),username('vijay'),'****',dbname('default'),query('analyze table default.test01 compute statistics'));
```

The function looks like :

```
static SimpleRegexMask::Ptr newUDFMask(const String &udfName, const int paramPos)
{

   return SimpleRegexMask::newInstance(
         udfName,
         udfName + "([^[:alpha:]]*)\\((([^,]*,){" + toString(paramPos - 1) + "})([^,]*)(,[^\\)]*)\\)",
         udfName + "\\1\\(\\2'****'\\5\\)"
         );
}
```

These are the functions in the above one. I hope it explains what I am trying to do

```
 static Ptr newInstance(
      const String &baseRegex,
      const String &replaceRegex,
      const String &matchFormatString
      )
   {
      return new SimpleRegexMask(baseRegex, replaceRegex, matchFormatString);
   }


SimpleRegexMask::SimpleRegexMask(
   const String &baseRegex,
   const String &replaceRegex,
   const String &matchFormatString
   )
{
   try {
      basePattern_ = boost::regex(
         baseRegex, boost::regex_constants::icase|boost::regex_constants::perl
         );
      replacePattern_ = boost::regex(
         replaceRegex, boost::regex_constants::icase|boost::regex_constants::perl
         );
      matchFormatString_ = matchFormatString;
   } catch (const boost::regex_error& ex) {
      // programming error i.e. the regex supplied is not valid
      NOT_REACHED;
   }
}
```

However, I want to modify the string to

```
 select * from run_on_hive(server('hdp230m2.labs.teradata.com'),username('vijay'),password('****'),dbname('default'),query('analyze table default.test01 compute statistics'));
```

How shall I modify the above function to do that? Where am I going wrong. Please let me know.
TIA.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: It is not failing. It is not modifying the string as i expect it to do!! I have written properly in question.

Comment: I have added what I functions I am using and what output is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
return SimpleRegexMask::newInstance(
     udfName,
     "(" + udfName + "[^[:alpha:]]*)\\(((?:[^,]*,){" + toString(paramPos - 1) + "}[^,(]*\\(['\"])[^,'\"]*(['\"]\\),[^)]*)\\)",
     "\\1\\(\\2****\\3\\)"
 );
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NKEtzg/1).

I optimized capturing group usage here (reducing their number) and used `[^,(]*\\(['\"])[^,'\"]*(['\"]\\)` pattern to match the `password` part the following way: captures `password('` or `password("` into Group 2, then just match any 0+ chars other than `,`, `"` or `'`, and then capture the `')` or `")` into the subsequent capturing group.

Note that the UDF name is captured into Group 1 and you do not need to hardcode it in the replacement string. So, if it is `RUN_ON_HIVE` in the string, it will be `RUN_ON_HIVE` in the result even if you have `run_on_hive` in the pattern (since you are using a case insensitive modifier).

Comment: How can I modify the code so that it  sanitizes the password at any position? I do not want to send the paramPos. I want to sanitize the string if it has password in it

Comment: I tried this but this is not working:
return SimpleRegexMask::newInstance(
      udfName,
      udfName + "password+(\').*(\')",
      udfName + "PASSWORD '****'"
      );

Comment: @hydra123 Probably, `"("+udfName+".*?password\\(')[^']+('\\))"` and replace with `"\\1****\\2"`

Comment: return SimpleRegexMask::newInstance(
      udfName,
      "("+udfName+".*?password\\(')[^']+('\\))",
      udfName + "\\1****\\2"
      );

Like this?

Comment: Do not use `udfName +` in the replacement, it is already in Group 1. Use it just as I wrote.

Comment: It is not getting sanitized. I am using this code:
return SimpleRegexMask::newInstance(
      udfName,
      "("+udfName+".*?password\\(')[^']+('\\))",
      "\\1****\\2"
      );

Is there a bracket which I am using wrongly?

Comment: @hydra123 Sorry, I confused backreference syntax. See http://rextester.com/OSC33794.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171130/discussion-between-hydra123-and-wiktor-stribizew).