# C++ std::regex confusion

Tags: c++, regex

While working on a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345834/2015579), I came up with the following c++ regex:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string remove_password(std::string const& input)
{
    // I think this should work for skipping escaped quotes in the password.
    // It works in javascript, but not in the standard library implementation.
    // anyone have any ideas?
    // (.*password\(("|'))(?:\\\2|[^\2])*?(\2.*)
//    const char prog[] = R"__regex((.*password\(')([^']*)('.*)))__regex";
    const char prog[] = R"__regex((.*password\(("|'))(?:\\\2|[^\2])*?(\2.*))__regex";
    auto reg = std::regex(prog, std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type::ECMAScript);
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex_match(input, match, reg);
    // match[0] is the entire string
    // match[1] is pre-password
    // match[2] is the password
    // match[3] is post-password
    return match[1].str() + "********" + match[3].str();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto test_string = R"__(select * from run_on_hive(server('hdp230m2.labs.teradata.com'),username('vijay'),password('vijay'),dbname('default'),query('analyze table default.test01 compute statistics'));)__";

    std::cout << remove_password(test_string);
}
```

I wanted to capture passwords, even if they contained an escaped quote or double-quote.

However the regex does not compile in clang or gcc.

It compiles correctly in regex101.com when using the javascript syntax.

Am I wrong, or is the implementation incorrect?

Comment: The error is *Unexpected character in bracket expression.* You cannot use backreferences inside bracket expressions. You need `R"((.*password\(("|'))(?:\\\2|(?!\2).)*?(\2.*))"`, or better, `R"((.*password\((["']))(?:\\\2|(?!\2).)*?(\2.*))"`. After removing `std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type::ECMAScript`, [it works](https://ideone.com/b5ugr6).

Comment: Try with `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript`. Or just remove that because it is already the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `ECMAScript` is the default flavor in C++ `std::regex`, you do not have to specify it explicitly. At any rate, `std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type::ECMAScript` causes one error here since the compiler expects a [`std::regex_constants`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_constants/) value here, and the simplest  fix is to remove it or use `std::regex(prog, std::regex_constants::ECMAScript)`.

The `[^\2]` pattern causes the second issue, *Unexpected character in bracket expression*. You cannot use backreferences inside bracket expressions, but you may use a negative lookahead to restrict a `.` / `[^]` pattern to match anything but what Group 2 holds.

Use

```
const char prog[] = R"((.*password\((["']))(?:\\\2|(?!\2)[^])*?(\2.*))";
```

See [your fixed C++ demo](https://ideone.com/2Q8KbK).

However, it seems you may use a "cleaner" approach using `std::regex_replace`:

```
std::string remove_password(std::string const& input)
{
    const char prog[] = R"((.*password\((["']))(?:\\\2|(?!\2)[^])*?(\2.*))";
    auto reg = std::regex(prog);
    return std::regex_replace(input, reg, "$1********$3");
}
```

See [another C++ demo](https://ideone.com/8y1swd). The `$1` and `$3` are the placeholders for Group 1 and 3 values.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. What on earth does `[^]` mean?

Comment: `[^]` matches any character in the ECMAScript regex flavor. Same as `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`. In other flavors, `.` with `DOTALL` modifier is usually used (in Ruby, with `m`).

Comment: hum. of course this works with gcc and fails on apple clang.
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: The expression contained an invalid back reference.`

Comment: No idea why, try with a regular string literal. It may also be related to the nested quantifiers. I hear apple clang implemenation is rather  buggy when it comes to more complex regex patterns.

Comment: Yes, I'm not surprised. Thanks very much for the help. I think it's time to switch back to gcc or real clang on apple anyway. Great answer.